Boldface \Delta in EB Garamond
I am trying to produce a boldface \Delta symbol. When using the normal font Computer Modern, I can simply use \mathbf{\Delta} which produced the right output. But in a document, I have to use the EB Garamond font. In this setup, the command \mathbf{\Delta} just outputs a normal \Delta. What can I do to remedy this situation?
Many thanks in advance for your help !
I suppose the EB Garamond font doesn't support boldface Greek symbols. However, I am convinced there must be a way around that.
Edit: In the end, I just had to print.
\DeclareSymbolFont{BLMletters}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lmDelta}{\mathbin}{BLMletters}{1}


Please provide your code

without seeing MWE, I can suggest you to use either \boldsymbol instead of \mathbf or try with the package bm and should use the tag \bm instead of \mathbf, but for correct solution, should post your MWE

EB Garamond doesn't have a bold weight. You might be using a package which fakes bold or have a EB-Garamond-like font which includes bold. EB Garamond doesn't support maths either that I know of except for ebgaramond-maths which I wouldn't count. And there is no workaround except that somebody could install the font with the capacity for fake bold glyphs, so that if ebgaramond-maths includes delta, for example, the installed font would provide a fake-bold version. Or you can use something like 'poorman's bold'. Or take delta from another font. But we don't even know which font.

EB Garamond Unicode math includes bold Greek math alphabet, so the \mbfDelta is supported with this font. You can try to process this code by OpTeX:
\fontfam[EB Garamond]

Normal Delta: $\Delta$.

Bold Delta: $\mbfDelta$.

\bye

My example illustrates that you should specify your minimal example where bold Delta doesn't work. You can see that there is another example (mine) where bold Delta in EB Garamond works.
